# Session key value is null if current request has not returned

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core

I'm trying to store data between requests to provide a way to update the progress of a process. I am trying to use the `HttpContext.Session` object to do this.

Here are two example endpoints (ignore syntax issues, these are made up):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/getTest")]
public string GetTest()
{
    List<Stuff> largeCollection = GetLargeCollection();
    for(int i = 0; i < largeCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        //Do stuff
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("progress", i + "/" + largeCollection.Count); // ie. 1/1000
    }
    return "done";
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("/getTest/progress")]
public string GetProgress()
{
    return HttpContext.Session.GetString("progress");
}
```

If I call `/getTest` it starts a long running process, and updates the `progress` key with the progress. If during this time I call `/getTest/progress`, the string that is returned from the `GetString` method is null. If I call the progress endpoint after the long running process is complete, the string that is returned is the progress.

I want the `Session` keys to be available even when the long running process has not returned, or if it never returns.

Why is this happening, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: 1. Does this only happen, when you write/read to the session for the first time? Read: Does it work, when you repeat it? In this case, the first method isn't able to set a cookie which identifies the session, so your second requests calls the end point w/o a cookie and has no access to the session. 2. Don't use state (Session or any other information) with WebAPI-esque APIs, it violates RESTful api principle and will cause you issues once you try to scale to more than a single instance. Every Request should be independent of a previous request and pass all data it requires with the request

Comment: @Tseng This happens any time I try and write data to the session and then try and read it before the controller method returns. It's as if the changes to the session are not "applied" till the method runs. This is an internal API for a single-page app, it does not need to follow the RESTful guidelines, it is just convenient to format the URL structure in this way.

Comment: Session isn't saved live, it's saved at the end of the request. It has a Commit method you can call to save it early.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/SessionMiddleware.cs#L116

Comment: Oh! You could add this as an answer? Also, is this a bad question, why is it downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

From my experience 'for' loop defers writing values to files till it has completed it's iteration. Hence I would recommend you to call a function instead, passing the value to be stored in-order to save Session string for retrieval.

```
public void StoreSessionProgress(string progress)
{
HttpContext.Session.SetString("progress", progress);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("/getTest")]
public string GetTest()
{
List<Stuff> largeCollection = GetLargeCollection();
for(int i = 0; i < largeCollection.Count; i++)
{
    //Do stuff
     StoreSessionProgress(i + "/" + largeCollection.Count)
}
return "done";
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("/getTest/progress")]
public string GetProgress()
{
return HttpContext.Session.GetString("progress");
}
```

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question, this just focuses on the code quality, which is of no concern considering I made this example up for the sake of the question. This has the exact same effect entirely.